# find largest prime factor using java

Tags: java, prime-factoring

I want to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143.I wrote the following code but I am not getting the correct answer. Please help me ...

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[]=new int[25];
    int large=0;
    long n=600851475143L;
    long x=(long) Math.sqrt(n);
    Top:  for(int i=3;i<x;i=i+2)
    {
      if(n%i==0)
      {
        n=(long) n/i;
        for(int j=0;j<25;j++)
        {
          arr[j]=i;
        }
        break Top;
      }
    }
    //System.out.println(arr);
    int num=arr.length; 
    for(int i=0;i<num-1;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
      {
        large=arr[i];
      }
      else
      {
        large=arr[i+1]; 
      }
    }

    System.out.println(large); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the correct answer? What did you get instead? What algorithm did you implement? Did you try to debug?

Comment: I don't see anything here that has to do with primes.

Comment: Actually, this program seems close to me. It seems likely to return the *second* largest prime factor of a number. My advice: start with a smaller number. For example, 21. What does your program do when you try to use 21 instead of six hundred billion and change? (Also, it could use a ***lot*** of tightening up. Like, what's the point of the array?)

Comment: Do you wrote it yourself? Do you understand it? Why you fill `arr` with same number and then try to find largest value in it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new to this.I need time to think of efficient algos.By the way,I caught the mistake.I had to declare the large variable as long rather than int.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LPF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int lpf= 2;
        long num = 600851475143L; 
        while (num > lpf) {
            if (num % lpf == 0) {
                num/=lpf;
                lpf = 2;
            } else {
                lpf++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest prime factor is " + Integer.toString(lpf));
    }
}
```

This is a simple implementation to find the largest prime factor of this number. 
A way to optimize this is to not increment lpf by 1 and instead set it to the next highest prime number.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new to this.I need time to think of efficient algos.By the way,I caught the mistake.I had to declare the large variable as long rather than int.